# How to set topAnchor constraint relative to the superview height

Tags: objective-c, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have two views: `toastView` and `view`. `toastView` is subview of `view`. 
I want to position `toastView` on the y axis by 80% of `view` height.
How can I do this using constants in the code?

I assumed that there is a method like:

```
[toastView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.heightAnchor multiplier:0.8].active = YES;
```

but i can't mixing `NSLayoutDimension` (width and height) and `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` (X and Y)

---

This is how it looks in the design:

[image: scheme of how it looks on the design]

Comment: 80% of view height ? means height of toastView = views 80 percent

Comment: If view height is 100, toastView.y should be 80

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick here is to set the **top** of `toastView` equal to the **bottom** of `self.view` with a **multiplier** of `0.8`:

**Objective-C:**

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: toastView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.view
    attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier: 0.8 constant: 0].active = YES;
```

**Swift:**

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
  toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 0.8, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks, 1 question, is this method an old way to do NSLayout constraint? It takes more code but could be used for relative topAnchor.

I found there is no `xxx.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holder.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 0.8)` such method when dealing with topAnchor.

Comment: @ChuckZHB, using NSLayoutContraint is an older and more complete syntax.  In this case, using the anchor style syntax doesn't give you access to the ability to set the .top of one item equal to the .bottom of another with a multiplier.

Comment: Ok, so it is the same to what I think, though I didn't confirm it before. Also I google it, that says NSLayout constraint is the raw API. Thanks, I learn a new thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in swift

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: view.bounds.height * 0.8 )
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([yConstraint])
    }
```

**Objective c**

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    NSLayoutConstraint *topAnchorConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:toastView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:(view.bounds.size.height * 0.8)];

    [self.view addConstraint:topAnchorConstraint];
}
```

Comment: It works, but I would not want to use method overrides

Comment: if you donnt want to use method overrides then simple add this line in `viewWillAppear()` and call `layoutifneeded()`

Comment: But this will be a viewWillAppear method override.

Comment: where you want to set them instead ? :)

Comment: its the same sir :) you can add that piece of code anywhere

Comment: In some cases, the view may have a zero frame. For example, when toast view is added to a view that is not yet on the screen (its view controller is not in the stack). In this case, view.bounds.size.height will be zero. The accepted answer uses view constraints instead of referring to its sizes (like view.bounds.height).